# Emulator starts in Android studio but my application does not

Tags: android, emulation

my emulator was working fine

but now when I run my program the emulator opens but my application does not appear  .. I am working with Android studio

Comment: Yup I'm facing that problem. What i do is, whenever emulator fully loads, i re run that module & it will ask me to choose either the emulator which is ONLINE or start another avd. So, just choose the ONLINE emulator and run it.

Comment: wow
finally ... 

that is worked with me 

thx a lot my friend

Comment: You're welcome. Check out my answer and accept it. So, it will be helpful for people to easily find who searches this in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup I'm facing that problem. What i do is, whenever emulator fully loads, i re run that module & it will ask me to choose either the emulator which is `ONLINE` or start another `avd`.

So, just choose the ONLINE emulator and run it.